# set value of input field by php variable's value

Tags: php, html, variables

I have a simple php calculator which code is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP calculator</title>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="orange">
        <h1 align="center">This is PHP Calculator</h1>
        <center>
            <form method="post" action="phptest.php">
                Type Value 1:<br><input type="text" name="value1"><br>
                Type value 2:<br><input type="text" name="value2"><br>
                Operator:<br><input type="text" name="sign"><br>
                Result:<br><input type"text" name="result">
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </form>
        </center>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $value1=$_POST['value1'];
        $value2=$_POST['value2'];
        $sign=$_POST['sign'];

        if($value1=='') {
            echo "<script>alert('Please Enter Value 1')</script>";
            exit();
        }

        if($value2=='') {
            echo "<script>alert('Please Enter Value 2')</script>";
            exit();
        }

        if($sign=='+') {
            echo "Your answer is: " , $value1+$value2;
            exit();
        }

        if($sign=='-') {
            echo "Your answer is: " , $value1-$value2;
            exit();
        }

        if($sign=='*') {
            echo "Your answer is: " , $value1*$value2;
            exit();
        }

        if($sign=='/') {
            echo "Your answer is: " , $value1/$value2;
            exit();
        }
    }
?>
```

All I want to do is that answer should be displayed in the result input field instead of echoing them separately. Please help? I Know it's simple but I am  new in PHP.

Comment: Move the PHP code to be above the HTML form. Assign the answer to a variable, then echo the variable into the input value.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way to do it will be to move all the php code above the HTML, copy the result to a variable and then add the result in the `<input>` tag.
Try this -

```
<?php
//Adding the php to the top.
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $value1=$_POST['value1'];
    $value2=$_POST['value2'];
    $sign=$_POST['sign'];
    ...
        //Adding to $result variable
    if($sign=='-') {
      $result = $value1-$value2;
    }
    //Rest of your code...
}
?>
<html>
<!--Rest of your tags...-->
Result:<br><input type"text" name="result" value = "<?php echo (isset($result))?$result:'';?>">
```

Comment: @sam Did you remove the exit() functions?

Comment: @sam Sure you can, Add the php code(the part above the `<html>`) in another file(call it calc_logic.php), and before <html> just include it using `<?php require("calc_logic.php"); ?>`

Answer (score 3):

inside the Form, You can use this code. Replace your variable name (i use $variable)

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($variable))?$variable:'';?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input  class="qtytext-box" type="number"  value= <?php echo  $colll2; ?> >
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: I am using php echo for print value in input box