# Change textbox based on select

Tags: php, mysql, select, textbox

I'm trying to develop a little project and I got a little problem
I'm making a PHP page connected to a MySQL Server. I have a page where only the administrator have access and that page allows him to change users information.
So, I have a select that show all usernames on website and 3 textbox where can be inserted the First Name, Last Name and e-mail. 
My database update successfully, but what i'm trying to do is when is select a username on select the 3 textbook auto fill with that username information.
Here is an image that explains better what I would like to do.
Sorry for my english and thanks to all
http://s3.postimg.org/da9srvh5f/table_copy.jpg

Comment: You have to do this in Javascript.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I tried to answer, but I found it against the rules of stackoverflow because you have to show what you have tried for to access what do you need to make accurate answer. In general, when we use the clause "if you have" in the answer, so the question is regarded to be ambiguous. Please try to refine your question supply it with some code that you have.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reload()   {
    var val=document.getElementById("c-name").value;
    self.location="your_url.php?name=" + val ;
    //alert(val);
}
</script>
<form name="data" action="your_url.php" method="post">
<table id="tbl">
    <tr>
    <td>Name </td>
    <td>
    <select id="c-name" name="name" onChange="reload()" style="width:340px;">
    <option value="">Select Name</option>
    <option value="abc">ABC</option>
    <option value="xyz">XYZ</option>
    <option value="mno">MNO</option>    
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr> 
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['name'])){
    $name = $_GET['name']; 

    $SQL_Data = "select * from client_data where cname = '".$name."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($SQL_Data);

    while($details = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname" class="c1" value="<?=$details['fname']?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="c7" name="lname" value="<?=$details['lname']?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>User Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="c7" name="uname" value="<?=$details['uname']?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    } } 
    ?>
    <tr><td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have your PHP backend return JSON data to your frontend.  Then, with javascript, do something like:

`document.getElementsById('ID').Value = VALUE;`

Where `ID` is the Id of your select and `VALUE` is the value found in your JSON data.

Alternatively, you could do this [purely in PHP/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483877/set-value-of-input-field-by-php-variables-value).